# Microsoft Graph change notifications -- For SharePoint Group for Tenant Level

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, office-365-developer, azure-service-bus

I have requirement that whenever there will be any new user added in in SharePoint Site Group. I need to put the details for that group, User, Site details in another Data base.

Can We user Microsoft Graph Change Notification for it?

Is Microsoft Graph Change Notification support for SharePoint Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph Change Notifications does not support SharePoint groups.

However it does support change notifications for **user** resource type. Check if you can do something using this resource/subscriptions.

**Reference**: [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: So For above requirement  I have to use only  Remote Event Receiver.